# Merging try_files

Tags: php, nginx

I'm new to nginx

I'm using php kohana and all works with me

```
    root   /var/www/html;
    index index.php  index.html index.htm;

    location / {
                # don’t check $uri/, send to php for nice error message
                try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string;
    }
```

But I need also to hide my html extension

I don't know how to add `try_files $uri.html $uri $uri/ =404;` to the exist  try_files from above.

========Update=====

The solution is

```
try_files $uri $uri.html /index.php?$query_string;
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this block to your existing file,

```
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri.html /index.php?$query_string;
    }
```

The term after location is directory where rules needs to be applied.

`/` is for root directory